# GROUP_CONCAT around CONCAT gives an error - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I'm trying to GROUP_CONCAT the results returned by the following query:

```
SELECT
      CONCAT(p.product_name, " (", SUM(bp.quantity), ")") AS products
FROM product p
INNER JOIN booking_products bp ON p.product_id = bp.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

This query returns the following:

```
------------
| products |
------------
Shampoo (3)
Advil (1)
Dry Shampoo (4)
Cepacol (5)
```

When I try run the query below I get an error: "#1111 - Invalid use of group function". What is wrong with this?

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(p.product_name, " (", SUM(bp.quantity), ")") 
        SEPARATOR ", "
    ) AS products
FROM product p
INNER JOIN booking_products bp ON p.product_id = bp.product_i
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Surely it should return:

```
Shampoo (3), Advil (1), Dry Shampoo (4), Cepacol (5)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Afaik, Oracle is one of the few RDBMS systems that support nested aggregate functions. MySQL does not, so `SUM()` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()` is invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(products) FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT(p.product_name, " (", SUM(bp.quantity), ")") AS products
    FROM product p
    INNER JOIN booking_products bp ON p.product_id = bp.product_id
    GROUP BY p.product_id
) x
```

GROUP_CONCAT is not working because you already used SUM, which is a GROUP function.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It works when I leave `GROUP BY products` off.

Comment: Ah, yes. I will reflect that in my answer.